# What does "first" do in Ruby and Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rubygems

I implemented a feature that lets users set default profile photos and photo-album cover photos.

I have the following tables in my database:

- User(s) - has one profile, has many PhotoAlbums
- Profile(s) - belongs to user
- PhotoAlbum(s) - belongs to user, has many photos
- Photo(s) - belongs to PhotoAlbum

The action for setting a default profile photo is:

```
def set_default_profile_photo
  photo = Profile.find_by_user_id(current_user.id)
  photo.photo_id = params[:photo_id]
  photo.save
  redirect_to :back
  flash[:success] = "Default photo set!"
end
```

That works fine.

Setting my default album photo was a little trickier:

```
def set_default_album_photo
  photo = PhotoAlbum.where(:id => Photo.where(:id => params[:photo_id]).first.photo_album_id)
  photo.first.photo_id = params[:photo_id]
  photo.first.save
  redirect_to :back
  flash[:success] = "Default album photo set!"
end
```

This is the action that didn't work:

```
def set_default_album_photo
  photo = PhotoAlbum.where(:id => Photo.where(:id => params[:photo_id]).first.photo_album_id)
  photo.photo_id = params[:photo_id]
  photo.save
  redirect_to :back
  flash[:success] = "Default album photo set!"
end
```

I got it working, and the undefined `photo_id method` error went away, but that was after changing these lines from:

```
photo.photo_id = params[:photo_id]
photo.save
```

to:

```
photo.first.photo_id = params[:photo_id]
photo.first.save
```

I am not sure what is happening, and why that change made things work, and want to understand what is going on.

Comment: "First" has slightly different meanings depending on its context, but in general it means the first of something, and returns a single item. In an enumerable, it is the first element. In a database it is the first row meeting some criteria. Use `ri first` at the command-line and you should get a list of places `first` is defined and how to use them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`find_by_foo` returns a single object. `where` returns a collection (relation). Obviously you can't do `photo.photo_id` when `photo` is a collection of `Photo` objects (instead of a single `Photo`).

`first` returns the first object of a collection. So by calling `first` on the collection returned by `where`, you get a single `Photo` object that you can work with.

Note that `Foo.where(:id => bla).first` is the same as `Foo.find(bla)`, so you can just use

```
PhotoAlbum.find( Photo.find(params[:photo_id]).photo_album_id )
```

instead of

```
PhotoAlbum.where(:id => Photo.where(:id => params[:photo_id]).first.photo_album_id).first
```

Comment: This helped. Thanks... Also you example is easier to understand.

Answer (score 8):

I don't have commenting ability, so I was not able to comment on the above post, but I should point out:

`Foo.where(:id => X).first` is NOT the same as `Foo.find(X)`. `Foo.find(X)` will raise an exception if there's no record with id = X, while the other one will just return nil.